# what exactly is dynamic parallelism?

Tags: haskell, dynamic, parallel-processing

I am not sure to properly understand the difference between static and dynamic parallelism in Haskell.

Suppose I have a map function which I can easily parallelise either using `parMap rdeepseq f xs` or using `` map f xs `using` parList rdeepseq ``. But that of course creates far too fine granularity. So I use `parListChunk s rdeepseq` to have better granularity. So instead of creating sparks for each list element, I can create as many sparks as the number of cores (determined by `-Nx` option) or 2-3 times more to have a flexible load balancing.

But is the fact that I am adapting the number of sparks/threads based on the #cores a form of dynamic parallelism? I tend to believe no.

How do I achieve dynamic parallelism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am an amateur at parallelisim*

Chunking based on the number of cores seems wrong. Instead, chunk based on how much work should be done on a single core: significant enough that the core actually has to munch on it, but small enough that the entire task can be chunked in a significant way (more than 1 chunk). As long as the work of a single chunk is significantly more than the cost of context switching and scheduling tasks, it doesn't *really* matter if you have exactly 1 chunk per core, or 1000 chunks per core. If you want **minimal overhead** parallelism, then yes, break your problem into chunks in such a way that you can schedule exactly 1 chunk per core in order to complete the task. But if you want **dynamic parallelism**, then you need to have a feel for the cost of scheduling; there will be a little more overhead switching and scheduling tasks, but with adequately sized chunks, the overhead won't hurt much. If a task is chunked into fewer chunks than there are cores, then the task probably didn't need to be parallelized in the first place.